# Function only executing first "execute" statment

Tags: vimscript

I'm trying to make a vmap that takes a count and then indents all the highlighted lines so that the top one is  more than the line above it, while keeping all the lines' relative indentation. I have made it to this function and I'm experiencing some behaviour I don't know how to figure out. For some reason, this function will only indent the top line of the selection. I've tested it using `echomsg` instead of `execute`, and then just pasting the commands in explicitly and it works just fine. But for some reason when it's in this for loop, it only executes the first one.

```
function! Test()
    let above = line("'<") - 1

    for line in range(line("'<"), line("'>"))
        execute line . "left " . (indent(above) + 4 + indent(line) - indent("'<"))
    endfor
endfunction
```

Also, if there's a plugin that'll already do this for me, feel free to let me know.

Edit:
Putting this function at the top of the file, changing `execute` to `echomsg`, highlighting the function body, and then running `:cal Test()` give the following ouput

```
2left 4
3left 0
4left 4
5left 8
6left 4
```

Which is expected, so I don't understand what's going wrong when I use `execute`.

Comment: Can you show your vmap? Does adding `range` to the function definition (after the `Test()`) fix your issue?

Comment: @Heptite I haven't gotten that far. I'm just highlighting text and then doing `:cal Test()` with this exact function.

Comment: When you do that, without defining the function as handling a range, Vim will call the function for each line in the highlighted region.

Comment: Well I can unhighlight the text and then call the function and I'll get the same result because the function just uses `'<` and `'>`. And to be clear, I ran literally `:cal Test()`, not `:'<,'>call Test()`. Also, like I mentioned, when using `echomsg` instead of `execute` the commands come out as expected.

Comment: What does the output of "`:messages`" show? It could be that Vim is overlaying each echomsg with the next.  I can't reproduce the behavior you're seeing but I also don't think the function is working right.

Comment: see edit *hit minimum character limit*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the code `indent("'<")`. After your first execution, that value changes, causing the indentation of everything afterwards to not change. It can be fixed by setting it's value to a variable before you start the loop.

Answer (score 0):

By default, a function called in visual mode is effectively once for every line in your range.

To get the behavior you want you need to add "range" to the function definition:

```
function! Test() range
   let above = line("'<") - 1
...
```

Comment: didn't change the behaviour :(